# validate fields before submitting them in php

Tags: php

how can I validate the fields before submitting them to the other file and show error message in the same page like : *required fields

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if user is already login, then jump to secured page
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: Pro_Lesson.php');
}
?>
<html>

<head>
<title>PHPMySimpleLogin 0.3</title>
</head>

<body>

<h3>User Login</h3>

<table border="0">
<form method="POST" action="log.php">
<tr><td>Username</td><td>:</td><td><input type="text" name="username" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password</td><td>:</td><td><input type="password" name="password" size="20"></td></tr>
<tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
</form>
</table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to learn basic validation http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to validate the fields before the form is submitted, you need to make use of javascript.

Take a look at this simple jquery plugin:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

[10 more jquery plugins here](http://speckyboy.com/2009/12/17/10-useful-jquery-form-validation-techniques-and-tutorials-2/)

[One that does not use jquery](http://www.javascript-coder.com/html-form/javascript-form-validation.phtml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use sticky forms. For example, you have a session page (session.php) with a HTML form. If the user who wants to sign in doesn't write the correct user_name, you can display in the same page the error (action="session.php).

Answer (score 0):

You should use Javascript to validate the form before sending it to the PHP page, and in the php page you validate it again.

Comment: To not send the request to the server if the form fields are invalid / empty